# Is it possible to have $\mathbb E S_n \to \infty$ but $\inf S_n = -\infty$ a.s.?

Tags: probability-theory

The original question is:

> Let $X_1, X_2, \ldots$ be i.i.d. with $\mathbb P (X_1 = 1) = p > 1/2$ and $\mathbb P (X_1 = −1) = 1 − p$, and let $S_n = X_1 + \cdots + X_n$. Let $\alpha = \inf\{m : S_m > 0\}$ and $\beta = \inf\{n : S_n < 0\}$.
>   Show that $\mathbb P (\alpha < \infty) = 1$ and $\mathbb P (\beta < \infty) < 1$.

I know that $\mathbb P (\alpha < \infty) = 1$ and $\mathbb P (\beta < \infty) < 1$ if and only if $S_n \to \infty$ almost surely. And there are only 3 other possible cases:

1. $S_n = 0$ for all $n$
2. $S_n \to -\infty$ a.s.
3. $\limsup S_n = \infty$ and $\liminf S_n = -\infty$ a.s.

As $\mathbb E(S_n) \to \infty$, case 1 and 2 are impossible. So if we can exclude case 3, then we are done. But how can we conclude that it is impossible to have $\liminf S_n = -\infty$ almost surely?

Comment: Is the first case supposed to say $S_n=0$ a.s.?

Comment: Also, how does $\mathbb E(S_n) \to \infty$ make cases 1 and 2 impossible?

Comment: @ByronSchmuland Yeah, you're right about case 1. It should be $S_n = 0$ for all $n$.

Comment: You could just use the law of large numbers to prove that $S_n\to\infty$ directly.

Comment: @ByronSchmuland Hmm, you're right.  $S_n / n \to 2p - 1 > 0$ almost surely, so $S_n \to \infty$ almost surely

Comment: You could close this question, or post yourself an answer.

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out in the comments, the law of large numbers entails that the following convergence holds almost surely:
$$ \frac{S_n}n\to\mathbb E\left[X_1\right]=p-(1-p)=2p-1\gt 0.$$
Therefore, for almost every $\omega$, there exists $N=N\left(\omega\right)$ such that if $n\geqslant N$, then $S_n\left(\omega\right)\geqslant n\left(p-1/2\right)$, hence $\lim_{n\to +\infty}S_n\left(\omega\right)=+\infty$. This was the only missing thing in the opening post.